# Does not display the image as a preview of the HTML video

Tags: html, html5-video

I have inserted in my video tag the code to show the preview with an image but this is not shown and I cannot understand why.

This is the code:

```
<video preload="none" width="100%" height="100%" autobuffer="true" controls="true" poster="mypath">
    <source src="mypath" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This is what appears to me inside mozila firefox:

[image]

I also tried on google chrome and the problem remains the same, what could be the problem?

Comment: Where you have added image path?

Comment: @KoshaSanghvi on video tag after controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code and also working in Firefox:

```html
 <video  width="100%" height="100%" autobuffer="true" controls="true" poster="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg">
       <source src="mypath" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```